# DropDownList Column in Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, telerik, grid

I have the following Grid Definition where the PreRemStatus column is not working properly with the ClientTemplate.  Is there another way I can accomplish adding a DropDownList Column in the Grid?  Thank you in advance to anyone who can shed some light on this.

@(Html.Telerik().

```
Grid(Model).
Name("grdCollections").
Columns(Sub(columns)

                columns.Bound(Function(o) o.PreRemStatus).Width(150).ClientTemplate
```

(Html.Telerik.DropDownList.Name("ddlPreRemStatus").BindTo(New SelectList(prc.GetRemStatusList().ToList())).ToHtmlString())

```
Groupable().
Sortable().
Pageable().
Filterable().
Scrollable().
DataBinding(Function(db) db.Ajax.Select("Grid_Ajax_Select", "PreRemediation", New With {.deployID = ViewData("DeployID") }).Update("UpdateGridPartial", "PreRemediation")).
DataKeys(Function(keys) keys.Add("CollectionId")).
Editable(Function(edit) edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)).
ToolBar(Function(tb) tb.SubmitChanges()).
HtmlAttributes(New With {.style = "width: 1150px"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Columns(columns=>
{
columns.Bound(p => p.Id)
             .Width(100)
             .Title("PreRemStatus")
.ClientTemplate(Html.Telerik()
.DropDownList()
.Name("ddlPreRemStatus<#= Id #>")
.BindTo(new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["PreRemStatus"], "Value", "Text")).ToHtmlString()
)
}
```